# Let's destroy the "homework" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Today in chat, mirka pointed out that the [homework](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag exists.  I think this is clearly a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> **If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves -- they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

A homework question can be about literally *any* facet of the Japanese language.  For example, [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19332/what-is-the-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D-vs-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D) is tagged [homework](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), but it appears to be about relative tense.  It's not about homework, and knowing that it's from a homework assignment doesn't tell us anything useful about the content of the question.

This tag is only on eight questions, so the best solution is probably to edit each question by hand, removing the [homework](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag and adding whatever tags are appropriate in its place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with this proposal -- "homework" is far from a technical term for Japanese, and could theoretically just be slapped onto any question that somebody's been set as a homework assignment by the looks of it. Because of this, it's not really a good classifier for questions on the site at all, and contributes no information to a question, nor does it help when searching for questions.

If you look into it more, most of the questions tagged as "homework" are also tagged as "translation". I think this is a much more valid tag for the style of questions they are. When you look at it, it's pretty much without doubt that "homework" questions are nearly entirely a subset of "translation" with no clear logic for which questions go into it. For reference:

**The 8 Questions tagged as "homework"**

*Of which are not tagged as "translation"*

- [What is the difference between ～たとき vs ～るとき](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19332/what-is-the-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D-vs-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D)

*Of which are also tagged as "translation"*

- [Translation of それを持って来させる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14535/translation-of-%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%82%92%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B)
- [Describing pain, a very painful situation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14533/a-very-painful-situation)
- [一番下のむす子 Translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/%E4%B8%80%E7%95%AA%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%80%E3%81%99%E5%AD%90-translation)
- [Name identification for 安田 味子, and "saying" using という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/translation-of-name-and-saying-sentance)
- [Using 前 and 後 with Time versus Duration](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14532/using-%E5%89%8D-and-%E5%BE%8C-with-time-versus-duration)
- [How are こと and こんな being used in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13740/how-are-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-and-%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA-being-used-in-this-sentence)
- [Grammatical purpose of changing 〜る to 〜な, and expressing "even"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13650/sentence-translation-with-strange-combinations)

Comment: Flaw retagged 7 of them, so I retagged the 8th.  It's done! :-)