# 宿題らしき質問についてのこれからの方針

Tags: discussion

## 日本語

当提示板では明確に宿題である質問にたいする対処についての方針が曖昧な気がします。

例えば、[この質問（誤字をさがしたら正しい漢字を書きなさい）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/102514/10627)は問題集などから写されたらしきものであり、コメント欄の@Leeboさんに同意したい所存ですが、過去にも["homework"というタグ(Let's destroy the "homework" tag)](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1468/10627)が存在していたり、METAやヘルプセンターで「homework」で検索してもそれらしい議論も説明も見つけられませんでした。
※上記の質問は宿題ではなくAI由来のものである可能性が挙げられました。

他のSEには宿題に対する方針が決まっているところも数件ありますが、StackOverflowでは「宿題であるか否かは無関係に、他の質問と同様の扱いをする」（[例１](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477)、[例２](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266979)）などと結論されています。自分的には、宿題は自分で考えて答え、初めて効果を成すものと考えており、その段階を踏まえてあるのならば問題ないですが怠けるための「裏技」としてここで質問しているとみなされる場合は答える気になれないと思っています。
※上記の質問が必ずそうであるとは決めつけておりません。

今後、このような質問がまた投稿された場合に行う扱いを提案して下さい。

## English

I feel like we don't have a clear policy to follow regarding homeworks.

For example, [this question (誤字をさがしたら正しい漢字を書きなさい)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/102514/10627) looks like copied from a student's notebook and I'm inclined to agree to @Leebo on the comments, but [there have already been the "homework" tag](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1468/10627) and I couldn't find anything on this topic in the META or in the help center. (It has been suggested that the question above might be an output from an AI instead of a homework)

There are other SE's that have a clear policy on this, but on StackOverflow for example, they have agreed to simply treat these as any other question and judge them by the site's rule (examples [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266979)). I personally think you only get something good out of a homework if you think and answer it by yourself first, and if you ask it then, there is no problem, but I don't feel like helping someone if I feel like they're just asking it here out of laziness. (I'm not trying to imply this is the case in the example above)

Please discuss about how we should be dealing with such questions in the future.

Comment: すみません、問題の質問は宿題ではなくChatGPT由来のものである可能性が挙げられました。それでも、宿題に対する方針は話し合いたいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

Merely my personal thoughts:

I don't think it's worth worrying about whether the person is using the site to answer their homework. At the end of the day, when they get to the exam and find they don't know anything, it's their loss. Or if they somehow get a job and don't know anything, the employer will soon get rid of them. I couldn't care less.

Whether it's homework or not, I think the usual standards for asking a question should apply. If the person has shown an earnest attempt to solve the problem for themselves then the question should be on topic.
If they haven't shown any effort but the material might be useful to other people then an answer would be helpful. Otherwise, just vote to close it with a polite message explaining that some research effort is expected. We used to have a close vote option like that; I wonder what happened to it?